# Showing Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects, when trying to dispatch data to store in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to **dispatch an action with data in its parameter**. Action is receiving the data but the reducer is not able to fetch that. I am using the `useDispatch` hook in this case. And I am using node v16.15.1 and npm v8.12.2

I have shortened the code for a better understanding

Component

```
const data = {...}
dispatch(sendData(data)); // the dispatch function will call onClick of a button
```

Action

```
export const sendData(data) => {
    type:ADD_DATA, //ADD_DATA is a constant imported for using as type 
    data
}
```

Reducer

```
const dataReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.data
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

combined it with `combineReducers()` function
store created using `configureStore()` 
the app is wrapped on `<Provider store={store}></Provider>`

Another Component

```
const data = useSelector(state=> state.dataReducer);
console.log(data);
```

In `console.log` empty state is displayed when rendered the component. But won't update onClick and gives the uncaught error *Actions must be plain objects*

Thank You...

Answer (score 1):

Your `sendData` action creator is wrong:

```js
export const sendData(data) => {
    type:ADD_DATA, //ADD_DATA is a constant imported for using as type 
    data
}
```

This isn't actually returning anything.  Because you have a `=>` and a `{`, it's a function body, not an object.  So, this is *actually*:

- a function body
- a label named `type`
- and a reference to `data`

instead of an object like `{type, data}`

You could put parentheses around the curly braces to make it an implicitly returned object instead: `=> ({type, data})`.

However, the *better* answer here is to switch to using our official Redux Toolkit package to write your Redux logic.  [Redux Toolkit is the the right way to use Redux today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today), and [RTK's `createSlice` API will automatically generate action creators for you](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#using-createslice).